# Garbage collector could not allocate 16384 bytes of memory for major heap section

Tags: c#, mono, garbage-collection, xamarin

I'm running some of my C# code on Mac with Xamarin Studio and getting the following error.

```
Error :Garbage collector could not allocate 16384 bytes of memory for major heap section.
```

I've tried setting an explicit limit on the managed heap and running with sGen following this advice :
 [Avoid Mono Cryptic GC Error Messsage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21970852/avoid-mono-cryptic-gc-error-messsage)

```
export MONO_GC_PARAMS=max-heap-size=2g
mono --gc=sgen MyProgram.exe
```

But I still have the same problem. 
Could you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Are you on a 32 bit machine/build?

Comment: Hard to help without complete project to check what is allocating memory where and how.

Comment: I think to be fair you need to show us more of your code as Yuri says.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not using **Low Latency** / **Sustained Low Latency** GC modes, they cause that kind of issues, don't use Batch either (it's old I think), unless you know what you are doing. You want to stick to Interactive mode most of the time.
You can read more about Latency Modes here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384202(v=vs.110).aspx